# How to make correct initialization of ComboBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I need show droppeddown combobox after start program.
I need in dropdown style only, not simple style.

[image]

This is simple fragment of my program:

```
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            CB1.Items.Add("1");
            CB1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
            CB1.DroppedDown = true;
}
```

But I found the watch sign as cursor till I click on Form in any place.
I guessed that my Form have not fully active state and wait for something.

When I click Form (or combobox or any control) by LBM, it activated fully and all works fine.

Of course the combobox is dropup then, so I need click combobox twice.
Еell me please what is correct initialization of such style combobox without "Cursor = Cursors.Default;"

Comment: _”But I found the watch sign as cursor till I click on Form in any place. I guessed that my Form have not fully active state and wait for something.”_ …? … No… the form is waiting for the user to select a combo box option since the code sets the combo box into a drop down state with… `CB1.DroppedDown = true;` … meaning the user is currently making a selection in that combo box. Comment out that line of code and the watch sign will go away. It is not clear what you are trying to do and what is not working as expected.

Comment: Why not omit most of that code and set the style in the designer?  There is nothing of consequence visually that can happen before the form is shown.

Comment: The Form is still rendering when the Shown event is raised. You can make the event handler async and write, e.g., `await Task.Delay(150); CB1.DroppedDown = true;` -- What you see is probably the Wait Cursor (what you call the *watch sign*) -- As mentioned, initialization code doesn't belong in the Shown event, move it to the Form's Constructor and set configuration properties (as the `DropDownStyle`) in the Designer.

Comment: As a note, showing a ComboBox with its ListControl already visible as soon as the Form is shown is not exactly something one would expect.

Comment: @Jimi the time may be not enough always. It's not a fixed time. I try with different values and sometimes works, but not always

Comment: @JohnG "Comment out that line of code and the watch sign will go away" - yes I did it a lot and I localized problem in such way. Problem was in " the form is waiting for the user to select a combo box option" while I have a lot comboboxes on form and only first should be dropeddown and my users no need in any watch-cursor.

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp and Jimi: I cannot set all styles in the designer as I need make setting tens controls in Foreach cycles:       foreach (var cbox in Program.GetAllChildren(this).OfType<ComboBox>()) 
            {
                cbox.GotFocus               += new EventHandler(CB_GotFocus);
                cbox.SelectedIndexChanged   += new EventHandler(CB_SelectedIndexChanged);
                cbox.DropDownStyle          = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
                cbox.DroppedDown            = false;
                dic_cb.Add(cbox.Name, cbox );
            etc....}

Comment: @Victor  I had read Your interesting profile and I wish I would collaborate in some interesting and complex projects  but I cannot write You private message here. Write me please to qqqq1961@ya.ru

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can simply wait until cursor is the default:

```
while (Cursor.Current != Cursors.Default)
{
    Application.DoEvents();
}

CB1.Items.Add("1");
CB1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
CB1.DroppedDown = true;
```

Application.DoEvents simply process messages from the window queue, so you can process message until you get that cursor is the default. In that moment, you can drop down your control without problem.

If you prefer, create a extension method for the Form:

```
public static class FormExtends
{
    public static void WaitToDefaultCursor(this Form form)
    {
        while (Cursor.Current != Cursors.Default)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
    }
}
```

And use it:

```
this.WaitToDefaultCursor();

CB1.Items.Add("1");
CB1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
CB1.DroppedDown = true;
```

NOTE: I use Cursor.Default but not to change the cursor. The form is processing messages and it's difficult to select a good moment to drop down the control.

Comment: YES! I forgot about magic antifreeze word DoEvents! By the way there is no need in While as I have very tiny queue. My code (really big code) now include right word in the right place. Thanks!  Application.DoEvents();

CB1.Items.Add("1");
CB1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
CB1.DroppedDown = true;